# How do I activate a Power Disc team up?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

I picked up one of the power discs - "Iron Patriot: Team Up".  It takes quite some time to power up, but having done that...  I can't figure out how to actually activate it.  This doesn't seem to be something that the instructions felt obliged to tell me.

What button do I need to press to activate the team up power ups?  I'm on Xbox 360, but equivalent answers for other consoles would probably help others as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be activated by pressing up or down on the dpad depending on how many power discs you have stacked under your character.

For example if I add one that gives me a shield and another that summons a character to help me one skill will get bound to dpad up and the other to dpad down.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting, I figured out you have to push the down direction on your d-pad.